# How to dissolve by two fields using C#

Tags: c#, arcgis-10.4, dissolve

I need to dissolve a feature class based on two fields for the dissolve_field parameter and two fields for the statistics_fields parameter.  Does anyone have an example of how to do this using C#?

The code I'm using works if I only pass in a single field for the dissolve_field parameter:

```csharp
ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Dissolve dissolve = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Dissolve();

//Set parameters values  
dissolve.in_features = "... path to feature class to dissolve ...";  
dissolve.dissolve_field = "Field1, Field2";  
dissolve.statistics_fields = "[NumberField1,MIN],[NumberField2,MAX]";  
dissolve.multi_part = "MULTI_PART";  
dissolve.unsplit_lines = "UNSPLIT_LINES";  
dissolve.out_feature_class = "... path to the output feature class ...";  

// Dissolve the feature class  
Geoprocessor geoprocessor = new Geoprocessor();  
object result = geoprocessor.Execute(dissolve, null);
```

Comment: Try putting the field list inside square brackets. "[Field1, Field2]"

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I continue to get the following error:

Comment: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters that ended up working are:

```csharp
dissolve.dissolve_field = "Field1;Field2";  
dissolve.statistics_fields = "NumberField1 MIN;NumberField2 MAX";
```

Which was a slightly different syntax that what is in the ESRI documentation.